# BJT collector power limit in pulsed usage?

Tags: bjt, thermal, damage

Assuming that my circuit respects the voltage, current, and thermal limits of a BJT, can the device be electrically damaged by exceeding an instantaneous collector power limit?

In other words, are BJT *power* limits only for thermal protection, or is there some other way that power can destroy the device, assuming voltage and current limits are respected? (In theory, this question could apply to both base power and collector power. But usually the base power is already limited by low current and voltage limits on the datasheet, while the product of the collector current and voltage limits is usually a very high power by necessity).

Details: I am looking to replace a BJT (Bipolar Junction Transistor) with a similar-looking one that is available this year. Both the original ([MJD122G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mjd122-d.pdf)) and the replacement ([MJD122-TP](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/MJD122(DPAK).pdf)) are rated with sufficient VCE (100V), IC (8A), and thermal power (1.5W) for my application. However, my application requires a transistor that can handle a 20W pulse for 1ms during cold start. The original datasheet gives a Safe Operating Area curve and thermal specs both suggesting that such pulses would be OK, while the replacement datasheet does not *say* that 1.5W can ever be exceeded, even for an instant. But maybe I could rely on common knowledge about BJTs?

Comment: I guess that SOA should be the same. Just draw (Uce vs Ic) and power hyperbolas for some "Duty cycle" (linear coordinates or logarithmic - straight lines). Just verify that you are "lower inside" The "problem" is that Rth is high (83 °C/W), so a PCB thermal area exchange would be needed?

Comment: There is not, as in SCR datasheets, something as i^2*t or i^2*sqrt(t) specifications. Only Vcemax, Imax and Pmax ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second breakdown limits of the SOA curve (as opposed to the simple thermal and current limits) of an unknown device are not really predictable. The limit is caused by current crowding in the die.

You are "probably" okay if the die is similar and there is plenty of margin in the original. You could consider testing to destruction to see how much margin there really is. And don't assume just one pulse is enough, do a longer term test.

Having been burned by this once, very, very early in my career, I'm going to suggest ample caution in direct proportion to the consequences of failure. Personally, I would source a device that is properly specified.

Comment: So, in summary, either shop for a part with a more reassuring datasheet, or, failing that, try to characterize the device myself, encouraged by various hints that it might be OK (similar part number, and original device supporting 200W pulses while I only need 20W). Good suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: When you say "if the die is similar"... is there any way I would know without trying to cut the package open? Would the dies be similar just based on similar VCE and IC and Darlington configuration? Any other hints I might look for?

Comment: You won't really know, though if you broke each open and compared the two under a microscope and the pattern and dimensions were similar it might give some small confidence. You could also contact the manufacturer and see if they have additional data.

Comment: It's more of a negative thing- if the die is 1/5 the size ...

Answer (score 2):

> *Can the device be electrically damaged by exceeding an instantaneous
> collector power limit?*

It sure can. Instantaneous power can destroy/harm the device without any significant warming at all. The original ON semi device has a proper SOA curve that allows for a short term peak power dissipation of 200 watts whereas the alternative device doesn't offer any help in that area.

[image]